# Node.JS - Express request returns undefined when when submitting a post request from a form

Tags: html, node.js, express, post, undefined

When I try to get an HTML form from using Node.JS/Express it seems to return a undefined value as the req.body returns an empty object.

**Node**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = '3000'


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))


app.use(bodyParser.json());  

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/',function(req, res) {

    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/signup.html')

});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
const FirstName = req.body.firstName
const LastName = req.body.lastName

console.log(FirstName)
console.log(LastName)

});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
if (err) console.log(err)
console.log('Local port started at', port)
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/" method="post"\>
  <label for="firstName"\>First Name\</label\>
  <input class="form-grid__item--field" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name"\>

  <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
  <input class="form-grid__item--field" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
              
  <label for="subscriberEmail">Email</label>
  <input class="form-grid__item--field" type="text" id="subscriberEmail" placeholder="Email">
          
  <input type="submit" class="form__button" value="Sign Me Up!">
</form>
```

Reformatted the code several times. Looked into the html form to ensure the action and methods where in place. When over body parser documentation to try and get more context but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` field inside `input` label is used for referencing the element in the DOM.

In order to pass the input as a field in the request you must give it attribute `name`

```html
 <input class="form-grid__item--field" type="text" id="subscriberEmail" name="subscriberEmail" placeholder="Email">
```

Answer (score 0):

The req.body searches for the name attribute in your form. Add the name attribute and then access them via req.body.theNameOfTheAttribute

```html
<form action="/" method="post"\>
  <label for="firstName"\>First Name\</label\>
  <input class="form-grid__item--field" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name"\>

  <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
  <input class="form-grid__item--field" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
              
  <label for="subscriberEmail">Email</label>
  <input class="form-grid__item--field" type="text" id="subscriberEmail" placeholder="Email">
          
  <input type="submit" class="form__button" value="Sign Me Up!">
</form>
```